# How to customize text in Bixolon SPP-R300 using commands

Tags: java, android, mobile, printing, bluetooth

How to customize the text using commands in Bixolon found here
http://www.bixolon.com/upload/download/spp-r300%20command%20manual_english_rev_1_00.pdf

** without using the library of bixolon **

At first... we're using this code with the APEX 3 Printer.

```
send += (char)27 + "F" +  "1" + (char)13 + (char)10;    
send += (char)27 + "L" +  "g" +  "0" + (char)13 + (char)10;    
send += (char)27 + "k1" +  " " +  (char)27 + "k3"  + (char)13 + (char)10;
```

Then now, we're using Bixolon SPP-R300 and tried to format the size of text, but never work -_-

Comment: How are you sending the data?  One immediate problem I can see-  if you're using a Java string, it uses 2 byte characters.  The printer appears to be expecting ASCII data, so it wants 1 byte characters.  Are you converting before sending?

Comment: yes, we use this, mmOutputStream.write(send.getBytes()); to send data

now, we need to make some text bigger or bolder, when i read the command manual which i included the link above, i can't understand how the command works, there's no example.. :(